# Canvas Triangle, Pentagon, Rectangle collision detection with eachother?

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

I have some code in which draws a triangle and returns an object with `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3` in it. I also have a rectangle drawing function which returns `x, y, w, h`, and a pentagon drawing function which returns `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5`. How can I make a collision detection function that can detect if rectangles and pentagons or triangles and pentagons have collided?

Comment: There's a handy function called [`isPointInPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) which can be used to implement collision detection.

Comment: [Here](https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-ii-collision-detection-for-solid-objects) is a nice article on that.

Comment: @AaditMShah. `isPointInPath` tests if an [x,y] point is inside a path (triangle, rectangle). It will not test if the triangle & rectangle are colliding.

Comment: @markE Of course. However, what you can do is test whether any vertex of one shape is inside the other shape and vice versa. It's not as elaborate as line-line intersection but if you're making an animation in which two shapes mustn't phase through each other then this is a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Test if any side (line segment) of the triangle intercepts any side of the rectangle**

If any side intercepts, then the triangle & rectangle are colliding.

- Test side #1 of the triangle against every side of the rectangle,
- Test side #2 of the triangle against every side of the rectangle,
- Test side #3 of the triangle against every side of the rectangle,
- If you find an interception while testing you can stop because the shapes are indeed colliding.

See below for details on "Are two line segments intercepting?"

Do the same side-interception tests for any other polygons to see if they are colliding.

**The test for 2 lines intercepting is reproduced here:**

```
// point object: {x:, y:}
// p0 & p1 form one segment, p2 & p3 form the second segment
// Returns true if lines segments are intercepting
var lineSegmentsIntercept = (function(){ // function as singleton so that closure can be used

    var v1, v2, v3, cross, u1, u2;  // working variable are closed over so they do not need creation 
                               // each time the function is called. This gives a significant performance boost.
    v1 = {x : null, y : null}; // line p0, p1 as vector
    v2 = {x : null, y : null}; // line p2, p3 as vector
    v3 = {x : null, y : null}; // the line from p0 to p2 as vector

    function lineSegmentsIntercept (p0, p1, p2, p3) {
        v1.x = p1.x - p0.x; // line p0, p1 as vector
        v1.y = p1.y - p0.y; 
        v2.x = p3.x - p2.x; // line p2, p3 as vector
        v2.y = p3.y - p2.y; 
        if((cross = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x) === 0){  // cross prod 0 if lines parallel
            return false; // no intercept
        }
        v3 = {x : p0.x - p2.x, y : p0.y - p2.y};  // the line from p0 to p2 as vector
        u2 = (v1.x * v3.y - v1.y * v3.x) / cross; // get unit distance along line p2 p3 
        // code point B
        if (u2 >= 0 && u2 <= 1){                   // is intercept on line p2, p3
            u1 = (v2.x * v3.y - v2.y * v3.x) / cross; // get unit distance on line p0, p1;
            // code point A
            return (u1 >= 0 && u1 <= 1);           // return true if on line else false.
            // code point A end
        }
        return false; // no intercept;
        // code point B end
    }
    return lineSegmentsIntercept;  // return function with closure for optimisation.
})();
```

---

---

**Are two line segments intercepting?**

> (attribution to [user blindman67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877726/blindman67) for assisting with the following example)

The function in this example returns `true` if two line segments are intersecting and `false` if not.

The example is designed for performance and uses closure to hold working variables

``` Javascript
    // point object: {x:, y:}
    // p0 & p1 form one segment, p2 & p3 form the second segment
    // Returns true if lines segments are intercepting
    var lineSegmentsIntercept = (function(){ // function as singleton so that closure can be used

```
    var v1, v2, v3, cross, u1, u2;  // working variable are closed over so they do not need creation 
                               // each time the function is called. This gives a significant performance boost.
    v1 = {x : null, y : null}; // line p0, p1 as vector
    v2 = {x : null, y : null}; // line p2, p3 as vector
    v3 = {x : null, y : null}; // the line from p0 to p2 as vector

    function lineSegmentsIntercept (p0, p1, p2, p3) {
        v1.x = p1.x - p0.x; // line p0, p1 as vector
        v1.y = p1.y - p0.y; 
        v2.x = p3.x - p2.x; // line p2, p3 as vector
        v2.y = p3.y - p2.y; 
        if((cross = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x) === 0){  // cross prod 0 if lines parallel
            return false; // no intercept
        }
        v3 = {x : p0.x - p2.x, y : p0.y - p2.y};  // the line from p0 to p2 as vector
        u2 = (v1.x * v3.y - v1.y * v3.x) / cross; // get unit distance along line p2 p3 
        // code point B
        if (u2 >= 0 && u2 <= 1){                   // is intercept on line p2, p3
            u1 = (v2.x * v3.y - v2.y * v3.x) / cross; // get unit distance on line p0, p1;
            // code point A
            return (u1 >= 0 && u1 <= 1);           // return true if on line else false.
            // code point A end
        }
        return false; // no intercept;
        // code point B end
    }
    return lineSegmentsIntercept;  // return function with closure for optimisation.
})();
```

```

Usage example

```
var p1 = {x: 100, y: 0};   // line 1
var p2 = {x: 120, y: 200};
var p3 = {x: 0,   y: 100}; // line 2
var p4 = {x: 100, y: 120};
var areIntersepting = lineSegmentsIntercept (p1, p2, p3, p4); // true
```

The example is easily modified to return the point of intercept. Replace the code between `code point A` and `A end` with

```
if(u1 >= 0 && u1 <= 1){
    return {
        x : p0.x + v1.x * u1,
        y : p0.y + v1.y * u1,
    };
}
```

Or if you want to get the intercept point on the lines, ignoring the line segments start and ends replace the code between `code point B` and `B end` with

```
return {
    x : p2.x + v2.x * u2,
    y : p2.y + v2.y * u2,
};
```

Both modifications will return false if there is no intercept or return the point of intercept as  `{x : xCoord, y : yCoord}`

Comment: Would this work for ellipses?

Comment: Now that I say that I just realized how dumb I sound

Comment: Chuckle ... I have moments like that, too. :-) Anyway, an approximate way to test if something is colliding with an ellipse is to get the bounding box of the ellipse and treat it as a rectangle.  Then test that bounding rectangle vs whatever. You can refine this test by collision testing the triangular corners of the bounding rectangle vs whatever, but with collision testing often "good enough is good enough" and the bounding box test is sufficient.

Comment: Nevermind. I made my own way by doing `if (obj1.x > obj2.x && obj1.y > obj2.y && obj1.x < obj2.x + obj2.width && obj1.y < obj2.y + obj2.height) {// Collided!}`. I have only tested this once and you can correct me if I am wrong anywhere :)

Comment: And I updated my drawing function to return only an x, y, width, height instead of each point